# how to run dmg on mac through java

Tags: java, macos

Please let me know how to run / invoke .dmg application in Java.
I used below syntax
`Runtime.getruntime.exec("sample.dmg")`
but it throws an error as "permission denied" with error code 13.  Please let me know how to invoke dmg.

Comment: Were you running this in an applet or otherwise with restricted permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Desktop.open(File file)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) which will use the appropriate opener for the OS. In your case on a Mac it will use `open`. This is better than `Runtime.exec` as you're not relying the exact location of the `open` command. Furthermore, this would even work on Windows if it had a DMG mounting application, such as Mediafour's MacDrive.

The bottom line is use `Desktop.open(File file)` to open a file with the operating system's default opener, that's what it's there for. Most people only use `Runtime.exec` as a last resort.

Comment: but the question is specifically about OS X and *.dmg*.  Also OS X guarantees that the *open* command shall be at that location, just as Un*x-like OSes do guarantee that doing a *kill -9* means insta-kill and getting back every resources an app use.

Comment: @CedricMartin: So, he should use the less convenient and reliable option just because in his case it won't break?

Comment: @Inerdia: don't make me say what I didn't.  I said that both OS X and Un*x made **guarantees** (unlike a certain OS).  When you're guaranteed to find *open* at */usr/bin/open/* and when the entire point of the question is to open a *.dmg* (*.dmg* being a concept totally alien to Windows), then it's not just futile and pointless but also misleading to make believe that *"not finding the open command"* and *"in the case he's not on a Mac"* are good justification to use *Desktop.open*.  *Desktop.open* is fine.  Don't justify it by making it sound like the OP wants to open a *.dmg* on Windows.

Comment: @CedricMartin, I don't believe the OS make any guarantee of the location of `open` or `kill`. Yes it ships with it in well known locations, but there's no preventing anyone from moving it renaming the files.

Comment: @SteveKuo: and hence breaking many utilities...  Btw regarding *kill*, I was talking about the guarantee that a *"kill -9"* was terminating the app instantly, no questions asked, and releasing the resources used by the app.

Answer (score 7):

A DMG file is not directly executable.  You need to use the Mac OSX open command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/usr/bin/open", "sample.dmg" });
```

You may need to have the full path to the dmg file but otherwise it seems to work fine for me.  Open also let's you specify the application to do the opening so you can do cool things like send this document in the Mail application as an attachment:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] { "/usr/bin/open", "-a", "Mail", "letter.pdf" });
```

I use open from the Mac command like this all of the time.